# Why isn't mapStateToProps updating my component's props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm learning React and Redux and I've wired up a simple app, but when I try to 'log in' to it, I'm finding my `mapStateToProps` function isn't working as expected. Any time I click my `Submit` button, the resulting props end up listing `username`, `password`, and `loggedIn` as `undefined` (`props` itself is not `undefined`), although the correct values are making it at least as far as the reducer. These props remain undefined both before and after the `props.history.push("/home")` line. On initial page load, the props are initialized correctly to `initialState`. Relevant portions:

Login Component:

```
import React from 'react'

const Login = (props) => {
    let user, pass
    const login = () => {
        props.login(user.value, pass.value)
        console.log(props)
        props.history.push("/home")
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={login}>
          <label> Username:
            <input type="text" className="form-control col-md-12" ref = {node => user = node}/>
          </label>
          <label> Password:
            <input type="password" className="form-control col-md-12" ref = {node => pass = node}/>
          </label>
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

export default Login
```

Login Container Component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { logIn } from '../redux/actionCreators';
import Login from './views/Login';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        username: state.username,
        password: state.password,
        loggedIn: state.loggedIn
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        login: (user, pass) => dispatch(logIn(user, pass))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Action Creators:

```
import * as types from './types'

export const logIn = (username, password) => {
    return {
        type: types.LOG_IN,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        loggedIn: true
    }

}
//I have more action creators below
```

Reducer:

```
import * as types from './../types'

export const initialState = {
   username: "initUser",
   password: null,
   loggedIn: false
}

export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOG_IN:
            return {
                ...state,
                username: action.username,
                password: action.password,
                loggedIn: true
            }

        // More Cases (LOG_OUT)...

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default loginReducer
```

Store Configuration (called in a Root component):

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {loginReducer, initialState as loginInitState} from './reducers/loginReducer'
import {messageReducer, initialState as messageInitState} from './reducers/messageReducer'

export const configureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            login: loginReducer,
            message: messageReducer
        }),
        {
            login: loginInitState,
            message: messageInitState
        }
    );
    return store
}

export default configureStore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `combineReducers()`, your state is going to end up looking like:

```
{
  login: { },
  message: { }
}
```

So in your `mapStateToProps`, you would need to do:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ login }) => {
    return {
       ...login
    }
};
```

The above is shorthand for:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
       username: state.login.username,
       password: state.login.password,
       loggedIn: state.login.loggedIn
    };
};
```

EDIT: An even shorter version (credit to [@markerikson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62937/markerikson))

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ login }) => login;
```

EDIT: OP was actually using browser submit causing the page to refresh and wiping out state. To fix can use `preventDefault()` i.e.

```
const login = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.login(user.value, pass.value);        
    props.history.push("/home");
};
```

Or not using a submit at all and instead just do `onClick` in a regular button:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={login} />
```

Comment: You could also simplify it to just be `return state.login`.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the tip. When I do this, I'm no longer getting a username, password etc. set to `undefined` in props, but it seems it isn't setting username, password or loggedIn at all. Instead I have the login function set as a prop. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: addendum: the previous was due to a syntax error. After fixing that, though, this is making my props revert (or never change from?) the initial state. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Are you able to use redux dev tools and the browser extension to see if each piece (action creator, reducer) are working as expected? or at least `console.log()` at each stage to determine this?

Comment: Seems to be, with possibly the exception of the `loginReducer`. It appears that the `state` being passed into the `loginReducer` function is the `initialState` - is this expected behavior? thought I remembered learning that `state` should be the next state. I'm also unsure what part of my code is actually calling the reducer

Comment: can you put `console.log(action)` above `switch(action.type)` in your login reducer and see what the output is?

Comment: Yes the result is as expected, `{type: "LOG_IN", username: "user", password: "pass", loggedIn: true}`

Comment: I think the problem might be because you are using a submit button; I don't think you want the built in browser form submit - see https://codesandbox.io/s/rl1xll8824 for the changes I made

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution did not work for me for some reason. After trying using the `preventDefault` method and the `button` method, I am still having props returned that are equal to my `initialState`

Comment: I got nothing then sorry man; hopefully someone else comes along and works it out - I copied most of your code to that code sandbox and it seems to be working the way I'd expect; is that the case for you too when you run it?